# Excel 2016 Macro to Import Tab delimited txt file into specific worksheet in the Workbook from where the macro was ran?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Excel 2016

Hi

I have a workbook called “Project” with a worksheet called, “Imported_Text”.

From sources online and through my own limited knowledge I have (against the odds) produced a sub (macro) that will open a user selected Tab delimited txt file, select only the columns I need and then excel places that in a worksheet.
That all works fine, however, Excel always creates a new workbook and places the imported data in it which I do not want.

I need to be able to run the Sub macro from the “Project” work and have the imported data place into the existing “Imported_Text” worksheet but I am unable to work out how.

I know I can record a macro, perform the import text file and while the macro is still recording manually select and copy the data from the new work sheet, paste it in my “Imported_Text” worksheet, save my “Project” workbook, close without saving the new workbook that Excel created and stop the macro recording. This would give me the VBA code to achieve my goal but it seems a rather convoluted way of having to do things.

Can any perhaps suggest a better way?

For instance can the result of the array be captured (to the clipboard?) just before it writes the results to a new file and instead pasted into the worksheet of my choice?

This is my code - it is far from elegant but it works,

```
Sub ImportTXT()
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog, result As Integer
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
'Optional: FileDialog properties
    fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fDialog.Title = "Select a file"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = "F:\"
    
'Optional: Add filters
    fDialog.Filters.Clear
    fDialog.Filters.Add "Text/CSV files", "*.txt"

    Answer = MsgBox("Are You Sure You Want To Import A Text File?", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Import A Text File")
    If Answer = vbYes Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename()

' ImportTXT code copied from Macro recording
        Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=FName, Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier _
        :=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:= _
        False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array _
        (1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 9), Array(8 _
        , 9), Array(9, 9), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 9), Array(12, 9), Array(13, 9), Array(14, 9), _
        Array(15, 9), Array(16, 9), Array(17, 9), Array(18, 9), Array(19, 9), Array(20, 9), Array( _
        21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 9)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
        :=True
    
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into the `QueryTables`.  (`worksheet.querytables.add`) Or use `Power Query`, available in Excel 2010+. Either one will allow you to import a delimited file and place the results on a worksheet in the open workbook.

Comment: I tried the Power Query but was unable to find a way of writing it in VBA as a macro bypassing the need to set the query parameters every time the macro is run.

Comment: @Kenny,, I've tried the VBA, you are using has lots of issues,, like after import data it saves the Workbook with  *.Txt extension,  also wipes out data from source file. Now check my post, the shown Macro is more versatile,, allows U to pick any Text file and every time asks where to paste the data,, hope this work for you.

Comment: @Kenny To understand how to use VBA to create a Power Query, suggest you use the macro recorder.  (Or you can use the QueryTables.Add method directly in VBA).

Comment: @Rajesh S It has a few issues but not lots while you code does have lots - did you look at the screen shot image I posted below? [Click Here](https://imgur.com/a/Ws4YUz7) The date your code writes to the work sheet is scrambled or garbled and unuasable.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld I have tried Power Query (Text transform in Excel 2016) and there are two issues. 1. it creates a link to the txt file thats being imported and throws an error if the text file is moved or deleted. 2. When recorded in a macro excel throws an error when I try and run the macro again.

Comment: @Kenny If you use Power Query, and you don't want to use it with a fixed file, you'll need to alter the connection string to refer to the desired file. You can do this with VBA.  Or, you could just modify your existing code to use the QueryTables.Add method.

Comment: @Kenny,,, what U are getting is,  as was in the source file otherwise data has been distributed properly column to column and are readable too,, in between I can see few apostrophes,,, it's not fault of the CODE,,, no where code generates any such ,,, if U are using CSV file change the Code line with `Application.GetOPenFileName`,, and I've mentioned as NB too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a modification to your code, which allows for picking different files, and writing them to a worksheet in your active workbook.

I used a CSV file for testing, but:

- The destination is hard-coded and you may want to change that.
- You'll need to change the delimiter from `comma`, which I used for testing, to `tab` as per your requirements
- You'll need to change the `TextFileColumnDataTypes` Array per your requirements.
- If you want the destination to be the sheet where you run the macro from, then just change `Set rDest = …` to  `Set rDest = ActiveSheet.Cells(row,column)`

```
Sub importText()
    Dim FName
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog, result As Integer
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
'Optional: FileDialog properties
    fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fDialog.Title = "Select a file"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = "F:\"
    
'Optional: Add filters
    fDialog.Filters.Clear
    fDialog.Filters.Add "Text/CSV files (*.txt; *.csv)", "*.txt; *.csv", 1
    
    Answer = MsgBox("Are You Sure You Want To Import A Text File?", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Import A Text File")
    If Answer = vbYes Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Text/CSV files (*.txt; *.csv),*.txt;*.csv", MultiSelect:=False)
    If FName = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Set rDest = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 1)
   
    With rDest.Worksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & FName, Destination:=rDest)
        .Name = "new 1_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Ron. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

*This VBA Macro solves the issue.*

```
 Sub ImportTXTFile()

  Dim vPath As Variant
  Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
  Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range, TextLine As String
  Dim rw As Long, col As Long
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, ary() As String, a As Variant

  Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook

  vPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("TXT (Comma Separated) (*.Txt),*.Txt" _
     , 1, "Select the file", , False)
     
  MsgBox vPath
  
  Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Sheet & a Cell", Type:=8)
  rng.Parent.Parent.Activate
  rng.Parent.Activate
  rw = rng(1).Row
  col = rng(1).Column

  Close #1
  i = rw
  Open vPath For Input As #1
  Do While Not EOF(1)
     Line Input #1, TextLine
     ary = Split(TextLine, ",")
     j = col
     For Each a In ary
        Cells(i, j).Value = a
        j = j + 1
     Next a
     i = i + 1
  Loop
  Close 1

 End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- RUN the Macro, shows the File Picker.
- Select the Text file.
- Macro shows the File with Path, finish with Ok.
- It Prompts to select the Sheet & the Cell to Paste the Imported data.

**N.B.**

- In this code `(*.Txt),*.Txt"` is editable it should `*.CSV` also.
- Save the Workbook as Macro Enabled.

Comment: Thank you, that works well to get the data where I want it but the data the macro inserts is garbled. see this screen shot Screen Shot](http://https://imgur.com/a/Ws4YUz7/).

Comment: @Kenny,, glad to help U,,, attached link is unable to open the SS,, better U check the source data,, otherwise I've tested is successfully,,,. Text file with comma separated values. If U feel U may up vote this also.

Answer (score -1):

I made a similar macro that reads the file in a single operation, and it also cleans up the data before placing items in the cells:

```
Sub RoundedRectangle1_Click()
    Dim Ret
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt")
    If Ret <> False Then
        readFile (Ret)
    End If
End Sub

Sub readFile(fname)
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String, tabData() As String

    Open fname For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1

    MyData = Replace(MyData, vbTab + vbTab, vbTab)

    strData() = Split(MyData, vbLf)
    For Row = 1 To UBound(strData) + 1
        tabData() = Split(strData(Row - 1), vbTab)
        For Column = 1 To UBound(tabData) + 1
            cellStr = Trim(tabData(Column - 1))
            If (Not cellStr = vbNullString) Then
                Cells(Row, Column) = cellStr
            End If 
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**Notes**

- This code will write over many existing cells in your spreadsheet, so beware
- I replaced double tabs with single tabs, and that fixed my cell placement problems in rows. You may need more sophisticated replacements there
- The double loop limits were derived empirically
- I had to use vbLf for windows txt files and vbNl for mac txt files
- This code places cells starting at 1,1, but you can change it to suit your needs

You can read this info in article form that I wrote at my website for my open source projects: https://www.virtualtwigs.com/articles/excel_macro_import_tab_delim_txt_article

Comment: How is this superior to the code posted in other answers? Why use this instead?

Comment: You appear to be the author of the linked article. When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam.
Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)

Comment: This solution is superior to other solutions it's fairly concise and it applies to any number of rows and columns (some solutions are just as flexible). The one advantage is in the cleanup of the text before it is broken down into rows and columns. For example, you can easily delete double tabs or double returns before placing things; this was a big advantage in my case as the imported text was flawed.